# I don't understand this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript

I have found the solution but I simply don't understand why not adding a return type fixes the problem:

I have a function that keys a TypeORM entity by ID instead of an array.

```
import { instanceToPlain } from 'class-transformer';

export default function keyBy(
  listOfObjects: object[],
  mappingKey: string,
): object // <--- i had to remove this 
{
  const data = listOfObjects.reduce((acc: any, currentVal: any) => {
    const tempObj = instanceToPlain(currentVal);

    if (tempObj[mappingKey] === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Mapping key:${mappingKey} not found in the Array`);
    }
    acc[tempObj[mappingKey]] = currentVal;

    return acc;
  }, {});
  return data;
}
```

I had to remove the object return type otherwise the following line gives the error in question.

```
const usersById = keyBy(users, 'id');
const user = usersById[message.senderId];
```

Just to try to understand I tried a few things, including:

`const user = usersById[Object.keys(usersById)[0] as keyof typeof usersById];`

But then I get:

`Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'never'.`

Anyhow, removing the return type of keyBy is resolves these errors, but I would really like to understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is : The type `object` shall not be used to type anything.

The type `object` is primitive, and every object is a subtype of it. But typing a variable with it is the same as typing it with `{}` and will therefore not have any key allowed

If you remove the return type of your function, TypeScript will infer it as `any`, because you return a dynamic object that is not typed.

If you want your function to return a dynamic object, you can use the generic type `Record`

```
Record<string, any> // will return a set of key value, where key is a `string` and value is of type `any`
```

But I suggest you to find a way not to use `any` at all. If you know what type you're expecting, maybe you should just define it.

If the return type depend on the type of `listOfObjects` in the parameters, maybe you can use a generic type.

For your example, i assume something like this should work :

```
export default function keyBy<T, K extends keyof T>(
  listOfObjects: T[],
  // Only allow key with a string value
  mappingKey: T[K] extends string ? K : never
): Record<string, T> {
   // Don't need to type `currentVal` anymore, and we type the return value of the `reduce` method
    const data = listOfObjects.reduce<Record<string, T>>((acc, currentVal) => {
    const tempObj = instanceToPlain(currentVal);
    
    if (tempObj[mappingKey] === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Mapping key:${mappingKey} not found in the Array`);
    }
    // We tell typescript that `currentVal[mappingKey]` is a string so we can index `acc`
    acc[tempObj[mappingKey] as string] = currentVal;

    return acc;
  }, {});
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `Record<string, any>` and `{ [key: string]: any }` Also yeah I try to avoid using any but in this case the only way I figure to do that is to add the keyBy function to Entity class/create a subclass itself which I opted not to attempt. I wanted keyBy to take any array and key it by a value so I think it is one of the cases where any fits. But I am open to an alternative.

Comment: From my understanding there is no differences between the two annotations.

Comment: I've updated my answer to propose a solution with generic types

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help anyone else new to typescript I went for Florent M.'s suggestion (read his answers for a better explanation) and this is what I ended up with. I removed instanceToPlain as well since I better understand how it works now it was not necessary. This is great as it also allows VS code to know what the types are when using the return of the function.

```
export default function keyBy<T>(list: T[], key: string): Record<string, T> {
  const instanceKey = key as keyof T;
  return list.reduce<Record<string, T>>((acc, currentValue) => {
    if (currentValue[instanceKey] === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        `key ${key} not found`,
      );
    }
    acc[currentValue[instanceKey] as string] = currentValue;

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const usersById = keyBy(arrayOfUserEntityInstances, 'id');
// type in vscode is Record<string, User>
```